# Alternative to using LinkedQueue?

Tags: java, concurrency, queue

I was wondering which is the best alternative to using `EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.LinkedQueue`.

In the following situation:

```
public class testQueue extends LinkedQueue implements TestInterface {

public void putTestObject (TestObject to) {
    put(to);
}
```

Should I be using `LinkedBlockingQueue` or `LinkedTransferQueue`?

I am only using the `put()`, `take()`, and `isEmpty()` methods

Comment: I don't know what the Java 7 `LinkedTransferQueue` buys you.  The `LinkedBlockingQueue` should be adequate unless this is some suport high performance collection.

Comment: *Why* do you search for an alternative? You seem to have a working solution. What's wrong with that? Why do you want to replace it at all?

Answer (score 1):

`TransferQueue` (which extends `BlockingQueue`) provides the additional operation `transfer`. If you are only using `put`, `take` and `isEmpty`, then it is enough to use a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: BTW, not that `isEmpty` may return `false` and a subsequent `take` may block. If that is a concern, consider using `peek` (which returns but do not removes the head element, and returns `null` if the queue is empty).

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedBlockingQueue` Would be fine.  Since you are not using any of the transfer mechanisms the LinkedQueue is very similar to LinkedBlockingQueue.  The only noticeable difference is that the LinkedQueue uses 1 lock while LBQ uses 2.

Comment: Careful. You make it sound like it's a bad thing for the LBQ to use two locks (whether that was your intent or not). The LBQ uses two locks, but they are independent of each other, that is, there is a lock for "puts" and a lock for "takes". See here for more details on this "two lock queue": http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf

Comment: @TonyRedwood My intent wasn't to imply good or bad, just stating the differences.  If anything two locks has better performance then one anyway.